# babel-plugin-i18next-extract - Extract translation keys outside react component

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

Im using **i18next**, **react-i18next** and **babel-plugin-i18next-extract**.

I have a "large" static json object. This json object has static keys that match translation keys.

```
// file: professions.js
//
// Large array with static objects
export default [
  { profession: 'translation.profession.teacher' },
  ...
  { profession: 'translation.profession.astronaut' },
];
```

While the following code displays the translations properly, the extraction of the keys does not work.

```
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import professions from'../data/professions.json';

function SelectProfessionComponent(){
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  return (
    <select>
    { professions.map( {profession} => {
      <option>{t(profession)}</option>
    })}
    </select>
  )
}
```

**How could I make babel-plugin-i18next-extract to recognized  'translation.profession.teacher', 'translation.profession.teacher' and others as translation keys from file professions.json?**

Comment: `babel-plugin-i18next-extract` doesn't support such use-case

Comment: By reading the docs I found out that it exposes `tfunctionnames` (https://i18next-extract.netlify.app/#/configuration?id=tfunctionnames). This allows for doing a noop function with specified name in `tfunctionnames`.

Comment: How this helps you? this only allows you to specify the function name. You won't be able to "look" into imports

Comment: What do you mean that I wont be able to look into imports ? Im not sure if maybe my issue or description is not understandable as Im intended to. I would like to extract all keys into a file. That's all. Below, I provided the solution that allows babel-plugin-i18next-extract to recognized 'translation.profession.teacher' and 'translation.profession.teacher' as translations keys and extract those into a file. If you understood something different, let me know to fix the description. Thanks.

Comment: All this plugin does is to search for function call (predefined with `t`) and extract its first argument (which is the translation key)... it can understand that the argument is a variable, but not more than that.
Out of the box, it ignores such function calls.

Comment: Maybe you can extend it, and add this functionallity :]

Comment: Hi guys, just opened a pull request for this:https://github.com/gilbsgilbs/babel-plugin-i18next-extract/pull/198. The idea is to rely on standardized names, so in your example, replacing "profession" key by a more explicit "i18nToken" key. Then using Babel we can detect this key in any object, and basically treat similarly to a `t("profession.astronaut")` call

Answer (score 1):

I found out a way to do it (maybe hacky, maybe not).

First, we do an idempotent function that returns what it receives.

```
// file: extractKey.js
export function eK(key) { return key;}
```

From the static data, we mark those that are acting as translation keys by using the `eK` function defined above:

```
// file: professions.js
//
// Large array with static objects
import { eK } from '../extractKey';

export default [
  { profession: eK('translation.profession.teacher') },
  ...
  { profession: eK('translation.profession.astronaut') },
];
```

And configure `babel-plugin-i18next-extract` to detect the function name `eK`:

```
// babel-plugin-i18next-extract config
{
  "tFunctionNames": ["t", "eK"]
}
```

That's all. Hope this helps to someone else.